# How can I change project settings in a ASP.NET project on the server?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012

I am currently developing a web application with C# / ASP.NET. I decided to set some settings via `PROJECT > MyProject > Properties... > Settings`.

I set some paths that have to get adjusted by hand on every new server, but you have to do it only once. **How can I adjust these settings on the server?** (I can access the server via FTP)

I tried to give an interface, but when I try

```
MyProject.Properties.Settings.Default.DataStoragePath = "D:\inetpub\ftproot\";
```

it says `Property [...] cannot be assigned -- it is read only`

Comment: Those settings are in the web.config.

Comment: You could store these in the web.config and use the web.config transformation which will automatically swap out the values for you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The settings are stored in the `Web.config` file. It's an xml-file, so it is quite easy to read and adjust the settings.